# Angular JS Geolocation get city

Tags: angularjs

I have following code in app.js. I wanted to capture location city in $scope.city variable. I have declared city outside geocode function, however city is not getting any value. need your help

```
// code as below 

app.controller('ydmoreCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $ionicModal, $ionicSideMenuDelegate, Categories) {
 (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(position){

      var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude);
      var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();  

        var city; 

            geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status)
                    {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK)
                         {
                                if (results[0])
                                {
                                    var add= results[0].formatted_address ;
                                    var  value=add.split(",");

                                    count=value.length;
                                    country=value[count-1];
                                    state=value[count-2];
                                    city=value[count-3];
                                    callback(latlng);
                           //         alert(city);
                                }
                                else 
                                {
                          alert("address not found");
                                }
                        }
                    });

      $scope.$apply(function(){

            $scope.city = "Pune";


      });
    });
  }
/*



*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to call

> $scope.apply()

after the city is set to

> $scope.city

inside to geocoder.geocode call